# Why prestashop synchronization module return error?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a module that synchronize the catalog of two stores and I have this error:

Link asker : http://www.joyeriaflores.com/modules/synccatalog/export.php?clef=5da437d241cb4
Export link : http://www.joyeriaflores.com/modules/synccatalog/sav5da437d241cb4.sql

> Warning: fopen(http://www.joyeriaflores.com/modules/synccatalog/sav5da437d241cb4.sql): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /home/relojeae/public_html/modules/synccatalog/import.php on line 207
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/relojeae/public_html/modules/synccatalog/import.php on line 211
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/relojeae/public_html/modules/synccatalog/import.php on line 219
> ERREUR import SQL

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight you have an error of right of access. It may be due to a htaccess.

Regards

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Thank you.